# Invalid cast from System.Data.SqlDbType to System.Data.DbType

Tags: powershell, sqlite, powershell-2.0

I was writing a script to import cookies to google chrome.

On Powershell 3 my script works fine, but in Powershell 2 I have a problem when trying to insert a byte array. The error is:

```
Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "Binary", for "Add" to type "System.Data.DbType":
"Cannot convert value "Binary" to type "System.Data.DbType".
Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to System.Data.DbType'.""
At C:\Users\root\Desktop\processhacker-2.39-bin\1.ps1:90 char:22
+         $sql.Parameters.Add <<<< ("@encrypted_value", [System.Data.SqlDbType]"binary").value = $byte;
```

Script as follows:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security #connect  DPAPI

$parent_dll = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path -Parent
$sqlite_library_path = $parent_dll+"\System.Data.SQLite.dll" #path to dll SQLite
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($sqlite_library_path)

$con = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
$path = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies" -Recurse

function decrypt_password ($enc_pass) {
    $bytes = $enc_pass.encrypted_value.ToCharArray() | % {[byte] $_}
    $decrypt_char=[System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::protect($bytes, $null, [Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine) #| % {[byte] $_}
    return $decrypt_char
}

$encrypted_array = import-Csv -Path .\c.txt
$con = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$path"
$con.Open()

foreach ($item in $encrypted_array) {
    $item.encrypted_value=decrypt_password -enc_pass $item
    $sql = $con.CreateCommand();
    $sql.commandtext = "INSERT INTO cookies (encrypted_value) VALUES (@encrypted_value)";
    $sql.Parameters.Add("@encrypted_value", [System.Data.SqlDbType]"binary").value = [byte[]]$item.encrypted_value;
    $fff=$sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $sql.Dispose()
}

$con.Close()
```

Comment: Please [edit] and update the question to a [mcve]. As currently written, it's a bit unclear where the `$byte` variable comes from.

Comment: fixed. copied script wrong

Comment: It's still not minimal. Reproduce the issue in 10 lines of code or less. Cut out everything that is not relevant.

Comment: Then, the error message should change as well, I guess…

Comment: removed unnecessary code. The main work goes in foreach block, rest is mainly setup and declarations

Comment: @joshbrown so change the cast to `System.Data.DbType`? What's the real question here?